# npm install packagename --save-dev not updating package.json

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

Are there simple or subtle reasons that `package.json` would not update after running a --save-dev? This is my command:

`npm install modulename --save-dev`

Run from the root of the project. The command succeeds, the new module shows up in the node_modules directory as expected. Help would be appreciated. I am using npm v 1.4.28

The entirety of my current `package.json` is:

```
{
    "name": "FooWeb",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Foo Web",
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.8.11",
        "gulp-jshint": "1.9.2",
        "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
        "gulp-sass": "1.3.3",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.4.0",
        "gulp-watch": "4.1.1"
    }
}
```

I do get warnings on install of a package that I have no repository field or README, but I think that is not related.

Comment: Did you check package.json permissions?

Comment: @Aaron package.json permissions are fine.

Comment: didn't know about `npm ls` pretty neat! in my case it outputs a green extraneous label in the tree for the module, and then errors with `ERR! extraneous: modulename@x.x.x. [path]`    I will keep troubleshooting down this path too

Comment: `--save` worked for me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603531/470749)

Comment: try using cmd and not the vs code terminal

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had this problem as well, and it was driving me crazy.

What finally fixed it was running `npm init`. This added a bunch of stuff to my package.json, but afterwards `--save-dev` worked as expected. Even after I removed all the new stuff added by `npm init`, `--save-dev` still worked.

Comment: Yep, that worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for that

Comment: Also worked for me. Didn't even add anything to my pre-existing `package.json`

Comment: Google brought me here ... I tried to install package like this: `npm i -s <package>` ... And "dependencies" field in `package.json` not been updated ... I made a typo :) ... `-s` must be `-S` (uppercase).

Comment: I had this issue, found out it came from the fact that I was working on a server. I moved my project locally and everything is alright now.

Answer (score 17):

This can occur in VSCode (and other editors) if you have your `package.json` open and you've made changes without saving.

The file **was being updated by npm on disk** but the IDE wasn't auto reloading it to avoid a conflict.

So the solution was to just close and reopen `package.json`.

Comment: (so in this instance the 'save-dev' was a red herring)

Comment: (Note: the shortcut for Save All is different in VSCode vs. VS)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you. I tried everything. But it appeared my case. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

I had the -g flag there, when I removed it, it worked as expected ...

Comment: Worked for me too. But why is that? What if I want to add a package globally?

Answer (score 6):

navigate to JSON file -> right click properties -> remove "read only" flag.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this recently, and figured out that for whatever reason it was Atom that was preventing the file from updating, even without the file being open.

I closed the editor, re-ran my npm install, opened the editor again and everything was as it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Mustafah ELBanna's answer helped me, but i want to expand his answer for other newbies like myself. Please correct me if I miss something important.

If you remove the `-g` flag, the module is not installed globally for your machine, but only locally in your project. If you also want it to install globally, execute the same command again but now with `-g` instead of `--save-dev`like this :

`npm install --save-dev [packagename]`

`npm install -g [packagename]`

It seems to me that something might go wrong when calling `-g` and `--save` in one line.

But again, I'm new to this and I appreciate anyone who wants to improve/correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue because `nodemon` was already installed globally.

I had to uninstall that first

`npm uninstall -g nodemon`

Then install it locally as a dev dependency

`npm install --save-dev nodemon`

The `package.json` file should then be updated. Sometimes your editor could also prevent the file from updating, so make sure to restart it if does not happen otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the commands stated in above answers but got success on installing `npm-upgrade` package.

`npm i -g npm-upgrade` then
`npm-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install the gruntjs using
    "npm install --save grunt-sass" but the package.json won't update

I did everything mentioned above but no luck. But funny thing is if i try adding a package say "underscore (npm install --save underscore)" the son gets updated. I am not sure if this is a problem with the nam as such. I did install as a super user.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen if you are not running the command from the `package.json` directory.

Will happen if you are placed in folder `Project` instead of `Project\ClientApp` for example.

You will notice that you only get a `package-lock.json` in the wrong location if this happens.

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in my package.json that was causing this for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was i copied the command from notepad++ it  may have had special chars in there or it was the spaces, and it was not updating my package.json.

e.g. did not work; `npm install --save debug   pug  jwt-simple   method-override   mongoose`

Make sure when you install,  you clean up the command line, e.g. any spaces between each module, because there might be special chars in there as well depending on your encoding.

When i corrected it to this it worked.

`npm install --save debug pug jwt-simple method-override mongoose`

Also, please make sure the package.json isn't opened in an editor when you run the command, because not all editors handle this gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

After I used express generator I installed some packages with --s and none of them added to package.json.

Then I deleted the package.json and run npm init and all of them added without having to install again

Answer (score 0):

I have an `.npmrc` file that uses an `npm` api built in-house to fetch packages. My issue was that I was not connected to my company's `VPN`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to solve this was by using `npm install --save-dev moduleName` instead of `npm install moduleName --save-dev`. Using `npm install moduleName --save` works fine for me, though. Only when I use `--save-dev`, I have to put it before the `moduleName`. I hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You may first want to check your config (`npm config ls` command or `~/.npmrc` file). 
I had `link=true`.

In version 5.5.1, this option seems to be ignored when *--save* is active.
Given that *--save-dev* supersedes *--save*, the *link mode* is active again.

So for me things happens as if `--save` overrided `--link` which in turn overrided `--save-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When i installed some package, it was not shown on the package.json. So then I deleted the package.json file and ran npm init again. After that it was working and the packages I installed before was also there under dependencies.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your answer. Have a read of [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information. Also, once you get more reputation, you will be able to post this as a comment rather than an answer, which would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dependency from devDependencies in package.json file and installing again using only --save worked for me

Answer (score 0):

With the accepted answer still my problem not resolve, then I try to change syntax position
Previously I am using the following command to install the module to devDependencies

```
npm i --save-dev moduleName
```

Then I toggle the position of moduleName and --save-dev and the moduleName successfully added in the package.json file

```
npm i moduleName--save-dev
```

Then the the package.json file updated with the moduleName.

Answer (score 0):

**This happened to me on Intellij**

For anyone else having this issue, did you copy your project from an existing project?

If so, close Intellij and delete the `.idea` folder. (You can delete `node_modules` too get a fresh start)

Open the project again and this will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add another possible answer that proved to be the solution for me.

Verify whether you are in the directory of your angular project. I wasn't and hence the changes were not getting reflected in my package.json file.