# "npm install [package]" doesn't update package.json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I've been using Laravel and trying to use `angular-ui-sortable` and `angular-utils-pagination`.

I installed them with `npm`, but can't get `package.json` updated for `angular-utils-pagination`.

The file now looks like...

```
 {
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
   "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-ui-sortable": "^0.14.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

The point is that `angular-ui-sortable` is there but `angular-utils-pagination` is not. Both files are under `node_module` folder. As far as I understand, those libraries have to be under `dependencies` in `package.json` for them to be available.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried saving it with the `--save` flag? In the worst case scenario, you can always manually add it to your dependencies list, and it should work.

Comment: `npm help install`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add a `angular-utils-pagination` under dependencies try:

```
npm install angular-utils-pagination --save
```

It should now appear in the package.json file.

For reference, adding dependencies to package.json:

```
npm install <package> --save
```

Adding dev dependencies to package.json:

```
npm install <package> --save-dev
```

Good luck!

Comment: They why Npm specification says that `npm install [package]` saves default to `depedencies`   https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Answer (score 3):

In order to save the package in the package.json file as a dependency you need to write

```
npm install <package-name> --save
```

if you want to save the package as a development package only (not to be installed on production server) write the following:

```
npm install <package-name> --save-dev
```

To install dependencies from the package.json file:

```
npm install *installs all dependencies*
npm install --production *will only install "dependencies"*
npm install --dev *will only install "devDependencies"*
```

Comment: Just to say, it's now 2019, I'm using the --save parameter when trying to install Angular Materials in my (writable) package.json file... but it just doesn't update this file.  This npm stuff doesn't feel "finished" yet...  I eventually got it working by manually editing my package.json file.

Comment: @MikeGledhill there is something wrong with your configurations. Try the following: 1) Check file permissions. 2) Add .npmrc with save flag. 3) Try to reinstall latest node/npm. 4) Just use yarn if everything fails at this point!

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this for me was checking the permissions containing folder. My project folder was owned by root instead of my user which was causing the --save and --save-dev to not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the package-lock.json file and then run npm install  --save again.  The lock file is automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, `npm install --save` was not updating package.json.

Found the problem I've had that package in dev dependencies, so `--save` was ignored. To fix the issue I've needed to delete dev dependency and then run `npm install --save` again

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in the `name` inside my `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
npm install <npm-package-name> --save
```

And if this isn't working (like it happened to me), delete the folder node_modules and run the commands to install again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of `package.json` being open with previous changes and not seeing the changes made by running the command. Closing `package.json` without saving and opening solved the issue