# package didn't add to the package.json after install

Tags: angular

I tried to install @angular/fire to my angular project using this command.

```
npm install @angular/fire --save
```

But the package.json didn't update. How to solve this problem?

Comment: this might be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486000/npm-add-to-package-json-but-dont-install

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["npm install \[package\]" doesn't update package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603458/npm-install-package-doesnt-update-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it already installed or exist on node_modules folder.
Double check pakage-lock.json and node_modules folder one more.

Anyway uninstall it and install again will work.

`npm uninstall @angular/fire --save`
and then

`npm install @angular/fire --save`
again.

Comment: The @angular/fire only added to the package-lock.json, I can't see this on the package.json.