# npm install with --save does not save in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have `npm-5.3.0` installed on my arch Linux.

I create a new project with `npm init` and fill in the details. This creates a package.json file with the details.

After that when I do `npm install <package> --save`, the file `package.json` does not change, and there is no entry for dependencies in the file. I had installed the package globally previously if that matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install packagename --save-dev not updating package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079558/npm-install-packagename-save-dev-not-updating-package-json)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the `--save` does not work with global and I had `global=true` set in the `.npmrc` file.

Setting `global=false` in the file fixed it.

Comment: I'd also like to add to remove any `.npmrc` in your user directory (Windows), even if the `.npmrc` file doesn't contain the `global=true` line.

Comment: Thanks, it had only the single line containing global=false, so I might as well just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Check update is available 
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install

you have to change

"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "underscore": "*",
    "rjs": "*",
    "jade": "*",
    "async": "*"
  }

then run 
npm update --save

Comment: I want the npm to automatically change dependencies and not manually add the dependencies in the file. That's why I run --save in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

ı have solved adding npm 'FIRST' module from to dependencies manuelly in package.js this problem. Next, you can try npm install moduleName --save